# file with hash (#) in its name does not open in web browser

Tags: php, file, browser

> I  have a simple php web application in which user upload a file. the uploaded file can be accessed by other users.its been working perfectly ,recently a user uploaded a file with name file_name#234324. when I opened this file through my web application it gave me an error that file name does not exist. it is due to the presence of (#) in file name due to which browser is unable to locate it correctly.
>   **What should I do?I don't want to change the file name**

Comment: Browser _won't_ pass anything after `#` to server. Thus, the only 100% correct way - to prohibit such names. (Otherwise - provide alternative way to download - not only via direct file name)

Comment: "http://localhost/masood2/files/7255177-54540-01%20Art#5941.xlsx" so you are saying that in this link browser only understand till # part

Comment: The browser understands what the rest of it means, it just doesn't mean what you want it to mean in a URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#` has special meaning in URLs. You need to represent such characters with their [percent-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) equivalent.

Pass the filename through [`urlencode`](http://php.net/urlencode) before adding it to the URL.

(This will also protect you from XSS when a user uploads a file with the name `"><script>etc</script>`).

Comment: That would be `%23`, for the lazy.

Comment: The lazy will be vulnerable to XSS attacks when people start putting other characters in file names. Be *properly* lazy, use a well tested, existing function to do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

> What should I do?I don't want to change the file name

Well you really should want to. The hash part of a URL is not sent to the server and is reserved instead for interpretation by the client (browser). Only the protocol, server, path name and query string are sent to the server.

As part of any good file upload system you should either be enforcing valid filenames or modifying them as required.